Update to some entries in DB column that are YYMM to be YYYYMM
I have a DB table and one of the columns has the date in there in YYYYMM format. However, I have some entries that are just YYMM and I'd like to update these to be YYYYMM also - So essentially I need to identify the records and then update them to have '20' on the start.
Is there a quick way of doing this?
So for example, I have
YYYYMM
202410
and then also some that are
YYMM
2410
So I'd like to identify all entries that are only 4 digits in length and then insert '20' on the front so they all read 2024MM

A date in YYMM format? Like 2410?

Column data type?

VARCHAR2 (6BYTE)

Do you expect the 9901 to be changed to 199901 or 209901?

Actually you ask the wrong question. It should be rather "how to convert this VARCHAR2(6) column to proper DATE data type". Storing date values as string is a design flaw.

If the value has 4 characters only, add 20 before.
update tablename
set c1 = '20' || c1
where length(c1) = 4;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/jTscMdch

You can use TO_DATE with the format model RRMM and then TO_CHAR with the format model YYYYMM:
UPDATE table_name
SET    date_string = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(date_string, 'RRMM'), 'YYYYMM')

If you want to restrict the UPDATE to the rows with 4-digit values then add:
WHERE  LENGTH(date_string) = 4;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_string) AS
SELECT '2401' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2301' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '202401' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '192401' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '9901' FROM DUAL;

Then, after the update, the table contains:



DATE_STRING




202401


202301


202401


192401


199901




If you want to convert 9901 to 209901 then use YYMM instead of RRMM for the initial format model.
fiddle
